# Calculating Bird's Eye View with OpenCV

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, computer-vision, homography

Searching for an easy way to calculate a bird's eye view I discovered [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/driving/ref/birdseyeview.transformimage.html) method from Matlab. This seems like a pretty hands on approach to the issue of manual annotating the source and destination points. In general I would like to understand if there is a mathematical approach to calculating the source and destination points only from physical camera properties. Any code that takes the same inputs as the Matlab example but is based on OpenCV would me much appreciated.

I know stackoverflow is not a "go write my code" community, so even a helpful clue or any math would be appreciated.

Comment: Easy approach: Select 4 points from the camera view and warp the image applying [Perspective Correction using Homography](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/).

Comment: @Burak The hole point of this question was to avoid this procedure. But thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in your link that the input image must be undistorted. So, let's assume that we have an image that we know the Euler angles of the line perpendicular to image plane in real world coordinates.

Yaw angle is not important for our case. If you rotate the image by roll amount (around the center pixel), then you should be able to find the 4 desired points by using the pitch amount. To find these desired points, we need to know the horizontal and vertical FOV values of the camera.

What are those 4 points? They form a rectangle when looked from above in the real world. The width of the rectangle is a design choise. For examples, the close points may be 45 degree downwards (between horizon line) with a total of 60 degree width, and the far ones may be 10 degree downwards with some certain width angle. We need to calculate that angle once.

Let `h` be the height of the camera, `x` be the distance between the projection point of the camera into the rectangle plane and the far edge of the rectangle (parallel to horizon line), and `y` be half the distance of the width of the rectangle. Given the example angles above, `x=h*cot(10)` and `y=h*csc(45)*tan(60/2)`. The width angle becomes `2*atan2(y, x^2+h^2) = 2*atan2(csc(45)*tan(60/2), cot(10)^2+1)`.

If the camera has, for instance, 70 degrees field of view, then the points at the edges are 35 degrees apart from the center. But the pixel which is between the center and the one edge is **not** 35/2 degrees apart from the center. It should be `atan(tan(35)/2)`.

Once you find the desired 4 points, you can use [`findHomography`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) and [`warpPerspective`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) functions, where the width/height ratio of `dst_pts` should better be `2*y/(x-h*cot(45)) = 2*csc(45)*tan(30)/(cot(10)-cot(45))`.

---

**Input:** undistorted image, roll and tilt angle, FOV of camera, desired ROI angles

---

[image: Angles]